# UIImageView shows outside its parents frame

Tags: ios, ipad, uiview, uiimageview

I'm developing a iOs app for iPad and I'm implementing a UIImageView inside a UIView. The problem is that if the position of the image view has a position out of the UIView that it is inside, you can see it. The code:

```
UIView *vistafunda = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(512/2, 48, 525, 651)];
[self.view addSubview:vistafunda];
vistafunda.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];

UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"hola.png"]];
img.center = CGPointMake(12, 200);
[vistafunda addSubview:img];
```

I would like that the image view was always under the view, so if the image is outside the view you could not see it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just make the containing view clip it's children

```
vistafunda.clipsToBounds = YES;
```